# replace a string in a text file with a string present in an array

Tags: java

I have a text file contain the content

```
data1
data2
data3
```

I need to replace the string data1 with data2 and data3 with data4, by looking at array.
xs is an array which contain data1 and data3.
xd is an array which contain data2 and data4

This code replace the content in the text file ie. data3 with data4 but it is not replacing data1 with data2.

```java
String originalFilePath = "C:\\Users\\GOMATHI\\Desktop\\str.txt";
String originalFileContent = "";

BufferedReader reader = null;
BufferedWriter writer = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(originalFilePath));

    String currentReadingLine = reader.readLine();
    while (currentReadingLine != null) {
        originalFileContent += currentReadingLine + System.lineSeparator();
        currentReadingLine = reader.readLine();
    }
    String modifiedFileContent, xy;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        modifiedFileContent = originalFileContent.replaceAll(xs[i], xd[i]);

        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(originalFilePath));

        writer.write(modifiedFileContent);
        writer.write(xy);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In both loop executions you modify the *original* (unmodified) file content. Thus, only the last modification will be visible.

You must only work on the modified one:

```
String modifiedFileContent = originalFileContent;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    modifiedFileContent = modifiedFileContent.replaceAll(xs[i],xd[i]);
}
```

The second problem is that you write the modification in each loop execution. Extract that and run it only once afterwards:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { ... }
writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(originalFilePath));
writer.write(modifiedFileContent);
writer.write(xy);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `writer` inside the loop, so

1. you replace "data1" with "data2" in the `originalFileContent`, and write the result to the file
2. you replace "data3" with "data4", again in `originalFileContent`, and write the result to the file. The effect of the first replace is thrown away.

Separate the replacement-loop from the writing, and also re-use the result of previous replacement(s):

```
String modifiedFileContent=originalFileContent;

for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
  modifiedFileContent = modifiedFileContent.replaceAll(xs[i],xd[i]);
}

writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(originalFilePath));
writer.write(modifiedFileContent);
writer.close();
```